# They go or they went?

Tags: grammar, tense

Let's say a general is making a promise to the public about criminals, and he say:

> I will absolutely catch criminals, with the best of my **abilities**, wherever they **go**

Or

> I will absolutely catch criminals, with the best of my **ability**, wherever they **went**

My questions are: is '**abilities**' correct over '**ability**'?, and if '**go**' is the correct word over '**went**'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I will absolutely catch criminals, **to** the best of my **ability**, wherever they **may go**."

"To the best of my ability" is a common English phrase.  It doesn't make much grammatical sense, but it does sound more natural.  "May go" is one of the few remnants of the subjunctive in English.  You could get away with just "go", but "may go" sounds better and implies that it is possible for the subject (criminals) either to perform or not to perform the action (go).  It implies uncertainty, since we don't know where the criminals intend to go.  You might also consider "may be" (not to be confused with "maybe").  It implies the possibility that the criminals have already gone.

"Wherever they went" just sounds weird.  Use "may go" or "may be" instead